# How to make Local Notification in android?

Tags: android

I have ProgressBar which had max. limit. As progress bar reached to max. value I want to show notification message window on current application.how to achieve it? I don't want notification on corner of screen, I want it at center of screen of current running application...please give some sample of it. What should I use to achieve it????

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [Toast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html).

Comment: nope...toast is temporary seen to user...i want to put button on that message,thats y i dont use toast..which will be use?

Answer (score 0):

use [SuperToast](https://github.com/JohnPersano/SuperToasts). This is a powerful library.

Answer (score 0):

Toast displays the notification on screen.

Here is syntax:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Your message",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Doesn't answer the specifics of the question, it is more about the position, placement should be at the center instead of corner